# Error executing code in html style attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am receiving an error when I try to execute code in a style attribute as followed

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkActivate" style='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Activate")) ? "text-decoration:none;display:none;" : "text-decoration:none;display:block;"%>'  runat ="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'  OnClientClick ='return confirm("You want to send email to user to activate his account?");' CommandName ="activate" Text="Send Email"   ></asp:LinkButton>
```

The error being thrown back is:
`Error: Unexpected '<' in tag 'asp:LinkButton'.`

I'm sorry if this question does not meet the community standards.
The code is also in C#

Edit:
Here is some more markup

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpHostUsersList" runat="server"  >
            <ItemTemplate>

                <tr class="odd gradeC" >
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AccountID")%></td>
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EmailAddress")%></td>
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FirstName")%>,  <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LastName")%></td>
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Phone")%></td>
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Address1")%></td>
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "City")%></td>
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "State")%></td>
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Zip1")%></td>
                        <td>
                        <%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Active")) ? "Yes" : "No"%>
                        </td>
                        <td> <%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Activate")) ? "Yes" : "No"%>                            
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkActivate" style='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Activate")) ? "text-decoration:none;display:none;" : "text-decoration:none;display:block;"%>'  runat ="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'  OnClientClick ='return confirm("You want to send email to user to activate his account?");' CommandName ="activate" Text="Send Email"   ></asp:LinkButton>      
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: the problem you're having is that the expression syntax is embedded within a string

Comment: How can I achieve the same result without embedding the expression in the string? Or what is another workaround?

Comment: I am not able to see any problem in this code. Everything seems absolutely normal. Have you identified what attribute is causing it? Most likely it's `style`, but could you try removing them one by one until the problem goes away?

Comment: One more question - where is this LinkButton declared?

Comment: Copy & pasted this code, no errors. I'd check what values are going into the Evals -- most likely the CommandArgument value.

Comment: I mentioned in the post that it's caused by the `style` attribute. the `LinkButton` is declared inside an `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: @Soulevoker, yeah, sorry, missed about `style`. More thoughts. It might be that the problem is not with the control itself, but with the markup around it. Can you post some more markup, say for the whole template where this is declared?

Comment: @Andrei I just edited the OP with more information.

Comment: you cannot bind a readonly property, Style property of linkbutton is readonly, make 2 css class outside your control, then write your conditional logic in CssClass Property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

Ok, your problem is related to Style Property of your LinkButton, which is [read only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.style(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public CssStyleCollection Style { get; }
```

But you can use the [CssClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass(v=vs.110).aspx) property

```
public virtual string CssClass { get; set; }
```

So you can do something like this:

Define you style tag outside your control:

```
<style>
 .myclassBlock{
  text-decoration:none;
  display: block

  .myclassNone{
  text-decoration:none;
  display:none; 
}

</style>
```

But if you apply your conditional logic inside your Linkbutton markup:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkActivate" CssClass='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Activate")) ? "myclassBlock" : "myclassNone"%>' runat ="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'  OnClientClick ='return confirm("You want to send email to user to activate his account?");' CommandName ="activate" Text="Send Email"   ></asp:LinkButton>
```

In your output you will see this:

```
<a onclick="return confirm(&quot;You want to send email to user to activate his account?&quot;);" id="lnkActivate" class="<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Activate")) ? "myclassBlock" : "myclassNone"%>" href="javascript:__doPostBack('lnkActivate','')">Send Email</a>
```

Because `'<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Activate")) ? "myclassBlock" : "myclassNone"%>'`, is not scriptlet, and will be output as plain text.

So you have to do something like this:

I have semplified your LinkButton:

```
<form>
<asp:Repeater ID="rpHostUsersList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpHostUsersList_OnItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td><b>Activate</b></td>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>

        <tr>
            <td><%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Activate")) ? "Yes" : "No"%> <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkActivate" runat="server" Text="Send Email"></asp:LinkButton></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
    </form>
```

In code behind I have create a Datatable on the fly just to have some fake data to bind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Activate = true;
            var ds = new DataSet();
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Activate");

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { true });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { false });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { true });

            ds.Tables.Add(dt);

            rpHostUsersList.DataSource = ds;
            rpHostUsersList.DataBind();
        }
```

So this is what you have to do to achieve your task:

```
protected void rpHostUsersList_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                var currentData = ((System.Data.DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["Activate"];
                var b = Convert.ToBoolean(currentData);
                var btn = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnkActivate");
                btn.CssClass = b ? "myclassBlock" : "myclassNone";
            }
        }
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: `<%# %>` and `Eval` is used exclusively in data bound context, inside data bound control. Style declaration is clearly outside of that

Comment: you are right, but you can put your style tag inside your databound control, yeah if the control is a gridview could be a problem

Comment: Interesting, never saw a css declaration inside a data bound control. It is going to repeat this css for each data item then, and finally apply what, the last one?

Comment: DetailsView or FormView for example? Never? We are not talk about best practice obviously

Comment: Oh, you are right. I was thinking about repeater, gridview and such stuff. Ok, that approach would work then

Comment: Ok, changed the approach :)

Comment: It's still not accepting the expression to even be in the string attribute. I'm using Monodevelop on linux if that helps any.

Comment: The compiler must be different, this code and the code you provided will work fine in Visual Studio. You could do this via an OnData bound event and in the code behind create a control with the correct CssClass for it.

Comment: @HugoYates That is a very interesting point. I bet if I did have VS, I would not have any of these issues. Alas, I am stuck with Monodevelop unless I can remedy it some how. I saw a setting somewhere in the program that does the complier was VS 2010. I will try to research how to emulate VS in monodevelop.

Comment: @Soulevoker I had deleted the answer because I was not convinced, but now I think I found the answer; Happy Holidays!